# Golang, proper way to restart a routine that panicked

Tags: go

I have the following sample code. I want to maintain 4 goroutines running at all times. They have the possibility of panicking. In the case of the panic, I have a recover where I restart the goroutine.

The way I implemented works but I am not sure whether its the correct and proper way to do this. Any thoughts

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var gVar string
var pCount int

func pinger(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        fmt.Println("adding ", i)
        c <- i
    }
}

func printer(id int, c chan int) {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("HERE", id)
            fmt.Println(err)
            pCount++
            if pCount == 5 {
                panic("TOO MANY PANICS")
            } else {
                go printer(id, c)
            }
        }
    }()

    for {
        msg := <-c
        fmt.Println(id, "- ping", msg, gVar)
        if msg%5 == 0 {
            panic("PANIC")
        }

        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)

    }
}

func main() {
    var c chan int = make(chan int, 2)
    gVar = "Preflight"
    pCount = 0

    go pinger(c)
    go printer(1, c)
    go printer(2, c)
    go printer(3, c)
    go printer(4, c)

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can extract the recover logic in a function such as:

```
func recoverer(maxPanics, id int, f func()) {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("HERE", id)
            fmt.Println(err)
            if maxPanics == 0 {
                panic("TOO MANY PANICS")
            } else {
                go recoverer(maxPanics-1, id, f)
            }
        }
    }()
    f()
}
```

And then use it like:

```
go recoverer(5, 1, func() { printer(1, c) })
```

Comment: Is the `defer` executed within the go routine? If yes, then I think we don't need to re-run the function in another go routine right?

```
} else {
   go recoverer(maxPanics-1, id, f)
}
```

Just wanna make sure we are not gonna end up with a "routine of routine" in case of failure.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Like [Zan Lynx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13422/zan-lynx)'s answer, I'd like to share another way to do it (although it's pretty much similar to OP's way.) I used an additional buffered channel `ch`. When a goroutine panics, the recovery function inside the goroutine send its identity `i` to `ch`. In for loop at the bottom of `main()`, it detects which goroutine's in panic and whether to restart by receiving values from `ch`.

[Run in Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ut1tdtfgrg)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var pCount int
    ch := make(chan int, 5)

    f := func(i int) {
        defer func() {
            if err := recover(); err != nil {
                ch <- i
            }
        }()

        fmt.Printf("goroutine f(%v) started\n", i)
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
        panic("goroutine in panic")
    }

    go f(1)
    go f(2)
    go f(3)
    go f(4)

    for {
        i := <-ch
        pCount++
        if pCount >= 5 {
            fmt.Println("Too many panics")
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("Detected goroutine f(%v) panic, will restart\n", i)
        f(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I am not saying that the following is more correct than your way. It is just another way to do it.

Create another function, call it `printerRecover` or something like it, and do your defer / recover in there. Then in `printer` just loop on calling `printerRecover`. Add in function return values to check if you need the goroutine to exit for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The way you implemented is correct. Just for me the approach to  maintain exactly 4 routines running at all times looks not much go_way, either handling routine's ID, either spawning in defer which may leads unpredictable stack due to closure. I don't think you can efficiently balance resource this way. Why don't you like to simple spawn worker when it needed

```
func main() {
...
    go func(tasks chan int){ //multiplexer
        for {
            task = <-tasks  //when needed
            go printer(task) //just spawns handler
        }
    }(ch)
...
}
```

and let runtime do its job? This way things are done in stdlib listeners/servers and them known to be efficient enough. goroutines are very lightweight to spawn and runtime is quite smart to balance load. Sure you must to recover either way. It is my very personal opinion.

Comment: I tried this method and it just keeps adding and adding. How do you limit the number of goroutines? It spawning goroutines which is the main problem

Comment: @Sakib you can do something like this
func main() {
...
    for i := 0; i < threadCount; i++ {
  go func(tasks chan int){ //multiplexer
    for {
     task <- tasks
     printer(task) //just spawns handler
    }
  }(ch)
 }
...
}